# Uniformly most powerful test for two-sided hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I need some help:

Prove that a uniformly most powerful test for a level $\alpha\in(0,1)$ doesn't exist for the test $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$ versus $H_1:\mu\neq\mu_0$, while $\mu,\mu_0\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It's not true in general, that's why you can't prove it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true in general. so you can not prove it. according to

[Uniformly Most Powerful Test for a Uniform Sample](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736322/uniformly-most-powerful-test-for-a-uniform-sample?rq=1)

UMP test for

$\left\{\begin{array}{cc} H_0: & \theta= \theta_0 \\
H_1: & \theta \neq \theta_0 
\end{array}  \right.$

exist. ( $\{x_i \}_{i=1}^{n} \overset{i.i.d}{\sim} Uniform(0,\theta)$)